# Firebase Function request url size limit?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting a 400 when doing GET requests to a Firebase Function with some rather large query params. A URL with length of around 2 KB works, while around 4 KB fails.

I would normally switch to using POST in this situation, but unfortunately it's not possible as an app I can't change is doing the requests on my behalf.

I can't find clear documentation on Firebase Function url size limits anywhere. Does anyone know of any docs, or better yet how to increase this apparent limit?

Comment: Can you please share the code you are executing, so we can help you better?